# Column value can't duplicate

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to generate an Excel file and and attaching to mail. In that excel file I am inserting the data. I am getting the BDname and Email. These two may duplicates. I want to show like these duplicate column value is single.

The result is like:

```
BDName|BDEmail|Process Id|Customer Name|Email
---------------------------------------------
siva  |a@a.com|a1        |hari          |h@h.com
---------------------------------------------
siva  |a@a.com|a2        |hari          |h@h.com
---------------------------------------------
siva  |a@a.com|a3        |hari          |h@h.com
---------------------------------------------
siva  |a@a.com|a3        |hari          |h@h.com
---------------------------------------------
siva  |a@a.com|a3        |hari          |h@h.com
---------------------------------------------
kumar |k@k.com|a4        |krishna       |t@t.com
---------------------------------------------
kumar |k@k.com|a4        |krishna       |t@t.com
---------------------------------------------
kumar |k@k.com|a5        |krishna       |t@t.com
---------------------------------------------
kumar |k@k.com|a6        |krishna       |t@t.com
---------------------------------------------
kumar |k@k.com|a7        |krishna       |t@t.com
---------------------------------------------
kumar |k@k.com|a7        |krishna       |t@t.com
---------------------------------------------
krishna|p@p.com|a3       |krishna       |t@t.com
---------------------------------------------
raju  |r@r.com|a3        |babu          |b@b.com
---------------------------------------------
raju  |r@r.com|a3        |babu          |b@b.com
---------------------------------------------------
```

Expecting result should like:

```
BDName|BDEmail|Process Id|Customer Name|Email
---------------------------------------------
      |a@a.com|a1        |hari          |h@h.com
       ------------------------------------------
      |       |a2        |hari          |h@h.com
       ------------------------------------------
siva  |       |a3        |hari          |h@h.com
       ------------------------------------------
      |       |a3        |hari          |h@h.com
       ------------------------------------------
      |       |a3        |hari          |h@h.com
-----------------------------------------------
      |k@k.com|a4        |krishna       |t@t.com
       ------------------------------------------
      |       |a4        |krishna       |t@t.com
       ------------------------------------------
kumar  |       |a5        |krishna       |t@t.com
       ------------------------------------------
      |       |a6        |krishna       |t@t.com
-------------------------------------------------
krishna|p@p.com|a3       |krishna       |t@t.com
  ------------------------------------------------
raju  |r@r.com|a3        |babu          |b@b.com
      ------------------------------------------
      |       |a3        |babu          |b@b.com
--------------------------------------------------
```

**My code is:**

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();       
str.Append("<table border=" + "1px" + "b>");  
str.Append("<thead>");      
str.Append("<tr>");  
str.Append("<td colspan='2' align='center'><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=2>BD Information </ font></b></td>");  
str.Append("<td colspan='7' align='center'><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=2>Customer Information</ font></b></td>");  
str.Append("</tr>");    
str.Append("<tr>");  
str.Append("<td  align='center'><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=2>BD Name</ font></b></td>");  
str.Append("<td  align='center'><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=2>BD Email</ font></b></td>");  
str.Append("<td  align='center'><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=2> Process Id </ font></b></td>");  
str.Append("<td  align='center'><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=2>Customer Name</ font></b></td>");  
str.Append("<td  align='center'><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=2>Email</ font></b></td>");  
str.Append("<td  align='center'><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=2>Mobile No.</ font></b></td>");  
str.Append("<td  align='center'><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=2>Case Number</ font></b></td>");  
str.Append("<td  align='center'><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=2>Product Name</ font></b></td>");  
str.Append("<td  align='center'><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=2>Quantity</ font></b></td>");  
str.Append("</thead>");  
str.Append("</tr>");      
var userids = db.Users.Where(x => x.RoleId == 1 || x.RoleId == 2|| x.RoleId == 3 || x.RoleId == 4|| x.RoleId == 5 || x.RoleId == 6).Select(x=>x).ToList();  
foreach (var item1 in userids)  
{  
var BDName = item1.FullName;  
var BDEmail = item1.Email;  
var list = db.Purchases.Where(x => x.SubmittedBy == item1.Id).Select(x => x).ToList();                                             
foreach (var item2 in list)  
{                                     
var CustomerName = db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == item2.UserId).Select(x => x.FullName).FirstOrDefault();  
var CustomerEmail = db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == item2.UserId).Select(x => x.Email).FirstOrDefault();  
var Mobile = db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == item2.UserId).Select(x => x.Mobile).FirstOrDefault();  
var ProcessName = db.Services.Where(x => x.Id == item2.ServiceId).Select(x => x.ProductName).FirstOrDefault();  
var Quantity = item2.Quantity;  
var ProcessId = item2.ProcessId;  
var CaseNo = db.ServiceRequests.Where(x => x.UserId == item2.UserId && x.ServiceId == item2.ServiceId).Select(x => x.SugarCRMCaseNumber).FirstOrDefault();                           
str.Append("<tr>");    
str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + ">" + BDName+ " </font></td>");  
str.Append("<td><a href="+""+"><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + ">" + BDEmail + "</font></a></td>");  
str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + "> "+ ProcessId + " </font></td>");  
str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + "> " +CustomerName + " </font></td>");  
str.Append("<td><a href=" + "" + "><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + ">" + CustomerEmail + " </font></a></td>");  
str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + "> " + Mobile + "</font></td>");  
str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + "> "+ CaseNo + " </font></td>");  
str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + ">" + ProcessName + "</font></td>");  
str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + "> " + Quantity + " </font></td>");                                     
str.Append("</tr>");  
}  
}  
str.Append("</table>");
```

I want the result like this

[image]

This is the result now I am getting:

[image: result image]

When I apply rowspan the result coming like this:

[image]

Comment: Where do you get the data from?

Comment: This looks like the question had new material added to it after receiving two answers, which potentially invalidates their work. I wonder if the new images should be moved to the end (since updates should go in chronological order to make sense to new readers), or they should be removed entirely and pasted in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

since you are looping through the userids(List) the next upcoming items will always be the one as same as the user above.

You can add `rowspan` to extend to multiple rows

```
foreach (var item1 in userids)  
{ 
   var BDName = item1.FullName;  
   var BDEmail = item1.Email;  
   var list = db.Purchases.Where(x => x.SubmittedBy == item1.Id).Select(x => x).ToList();
   // check
   if(list.Count > 0){
   //use rowspan to extend to multiple rows.   
     str.Append("<td rowspan="+list.Count+"><font face=Arial Narrow size=14px>" + BDName+ " </font></td>");  
     str.Append("<td rowspan="+list.Count+"><a href="+""+"><font face=Arial Narrow size= 14px >"+ BDEmail + "</font></a></td>"); 

     foreach (var item2 in list)
     {
      //the rest of the td
     }
   }
}
```

**EDIT**
Also use seperate css file to style the td > [Explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)

Comment: one more thing is the remaining td values for the bdname and demail are empty right. how can i remove the empty data of the column borders? means i would like to show only bdname and bdemail in the center by removing the empty cells.

Comment: @kumar I'm not quite understanding what you mean. Can you make a expected result and add it to the question?

Comment: Hi i just edited my actuall and expecting data tables. please once check it. please observe the bdname and bd email cells

Comment: @kumar Changed to what you want. You can use rowspan to extend to multiple rows.

Comment: HI H.Mikhaeljan please find the attached images.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYvba.png this is the result i am getting when i am applying rowspan.                                   str.Append("<td rowspan=" + i + "><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + "> </font></td>"); here i is list count

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYvba.png this is what i want exactly sry mistakes in links.

Comment: @kumar check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan)

Comment: Hi H.Mikhaeljan please find the below link for my new question and please help me.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114374/e-commerce-seller-free-calculator

Comment: @kumar thats not how it works. i can't help you with every question you have. Just ask your question and wait for a answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `LINQ` too. First you make a list grouping it by `user_ID`, second list will be as it is (i.e. the original list). Then you can `UNION` them into one. Below is the sample of how you can achieve.

```
        var list = (from tl in tempList 
                group tl by tl.id into g
                select new 
                { 
                    g.FirstOrDefault().BDName, 
                    index = g.FirstOrDefault().id, 
                    sort1 = g.FirstOrDefault().id, 
                    sort2 = -1, 
                    g.FirstOrDefault().BDEmail 
                }).ToList();
    int i = 0;
    var list2 = (from tl2 in tempList
                 let index = i++
                 select new 
                 { 
                     BDName = "    ", 
                     index, 
                     sort1 = tl2.id, 
                     sort2 = -1, 
                     tl2.BDEmail 
                 }).ToList();

    var listFinal = list.Union(list2.Where(x => x.index > 1))
                    .OrderBy(x => x.sort1)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.sort2);
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QnMPbe) is the working `dotnetfiddle`. Hope it helps.

Comment: HI DhavalR, its working fine. thanks for your affort on this. please check my edited format for excel. in actual result and expecting result.